# Google cloud storage using node js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node

I need to upload and share my documents using google cloud and node js. I have created a google cloud account and also made bucket,folder and object in google storage using console.developers.google.com web page.

I have some doubts

1. How many buckets are created for a single project(if it possible to
   create    1 million buckets?)

> 2. How to share a folder ?

3. If it possible to genarate auth token for accessing objects in the buckets?(to public, token changed in every request)

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: How many buckets are created for a single project(if it possible to
create 1 million buckets?

Answer: You can create as many buckets you want in one project unlike Amazon but keep in mind that bucket names are global namespace.

Question 2: How to share a folder ?

Answer: By share folder here I mean you want multiple representatives to access it. Please refer to this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration#using and check -> Central File for Shared Components

Question 3: Is it possible to generate an auth token for accessing objects in the buckets? (to public, token changed in every request)

Answer: What I am able to make out from this question of yours is you want to make a system to share files for various people based on token authentication.

You can do it via two methods, if done in programmatic way you can handle it on your own by deploying a system to generate tokens on request invoked by your system.